# Hibernate generate ddl using order in which fields are defined in class

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate generates column names (ddl) in ascending order.
Is there a way to preserve the order in which columns are defined in the class?
Like:

```
public class Fruit{

private int type;
private String name;

}
```

table should be:

```
Fruit (type, name)
```

instead of

```
(name,type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate team says it's a [known limitation](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2396344) and it's impossible to set the order. But you shouldn't rely on hbm2ddl when using Hibernate in production, it's pretty limited thing, for instance it can add column, but it can't remove it. Instead people usually create DB migrations with tools like LiquiBase or FlyWay or DbDeploy, this gives you more flexibility and control over the schema updates.